# Browser Back Button default behavior still executing on stop propigation

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an angular site in which I've inserted some code to make the browser back button behave in the same way as the back UI button. However when I press back on the browser I get the last visited page flashing for a second before the default behavior executes.

Here's a video to show what I mean - at the end I show the what clicking the UI button does which is what I want to emulate:
[Browser Back Button Demo](https://youtu.be/ulyvRVStBw4)

And here's the code I'm using in Angular:

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onBrowserBackBtnClose(event: Event) {
      // Stop default behavior of the back button
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();
      // If we can go back...
      if (this.canGoBack) {
        // Load the previous question
        this.questionService.previousQuestion().subscribe(res => {
          // Activate the question route in place of the previous page
          this.router.navigate(['question'], {replaceUrl: true});
        });
      }
  }
```

My understanding was that `event.stopPropagation();` and `event.preventDefault();` stopped this flickering behavior? Or is there something else I'm not understanding or missing?

Comment: instead of watching the `window:popstate'`, what if you watched the `'window:beforeunload'`?

Comment: The event `window:popstate` is not cancellable, so you'll always see the last page for a moment.

Answer (score 1):

If I was you I would rather use native Angular approach here. In this particular case you can implement [CanDeactivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanDeactivate) or [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) Route Guards.

In both of this interfaces methods uses asynchronous returns such as:

> Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cancel popstate event in the browser, read more about the event on [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event). That being said, you can update window history (technically a hack) and push current location again so that page will be navigated back to current page using:

> window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);

Not sure, how you can apply it to your code as I do not have working demo of your app, but it could look something like:

```js
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onBrowserBackBtnClose(event: Event) {
  // prevent browser from moving to different page
  window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
      
  // If we can go back...
  if (this.canGoBack) {
    // Load the previous question
    this.questionService.previousQuestion().subscribe(res => {
      // Activate the question route in place of the previous page
      this.router.navigate(['question'], {
        replaceUrl: true
      }); // you will need some other code to determine and navigate to next page if user chooses to
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Close but I still get the flicker of the last page

Comment: @webdevelopwolf could you please share stackblitz app with issue reproduced?

Comment: @WebDevelopWolf could you share more details?

Answer (score 0):

My way to fix this issue:
I have some element table and I can open each element detail page by click in row. After browser back navigation in detail page I need to scroll and highlight element row in table. For this i need to navigate by fragment(element id)

```
// if i have fragment
this.backQuery = window.history.state.query;
this.backFragment = window.history.state.fragment;
history.pushState(null, '');
```

And i need to listen browser back navigation event

```
@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event: any): void {
  if (this.backFragment) {
    let query = '';
    if (this.backQuery) {
      Object.keys(this.backQuery).forEach(key => {
        query = query + key + '=' + this.backQuery[key] + '&';
      });
      query = '?' + query.replace(/\&$/g, '');
    }
    window.location.href = `table-page${query}#${this.backFragment}`;
  }
}
```